Resource suggestions?
If I want to research binary stars (to find out about their properties from their light curves) and I need to know how to interpret light curves for the same, what would be a good resource to refer to? I am looking for a short-read.
Assume I have a first-year college-level understanding of mathematics and a basic idea of the related field of spectroscopy.

You mean eclipsing binaries? There is not much information on binary systems from their light curves otherwise.

aavso has tutorials on data analysis of light curves https://www.aavso.org/tutorials

You should read the AAVSO tutorials, especially the tutorial on light curve data processing, but you should also read the observing tutorials, so you get a better idea of where the data comes from (and hence understand its significance and limitations better)
The 5-Star Tutorial for Data Analysis covers the basics of how to look at a light curve and what it can tell you.  There are other other Online Resources for Beginning Observers.
